# HTML 3 divs- left, center and right positioning

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs with non known (variable) width. I want them to be positioned to left, centered and to right. I did left and right, but have problem with the center.

Example (what I want):

```
[[LEFT]                            [CENTERED]                              [RIGHT]]
```

But they are:

```
[[LEFT][CENTERED]                                                           [RIGHT]]
```

CSS:

```
#text_area_wrapper
    {
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #text_area
    {
        width:200px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #text_area_left
    {
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }
    #text_area_right
    {
        position:relative;
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id='text_area_row'>
                <div id='text_area_left'>Left</div>
                <div id='text_area_wrapper'>
                    <div id='text_area'>
                        CENTERED
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='text_area_right'>Right</div>
    </div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: See `flexbox` but at the moment you cannot achieve this with just floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place your middle `<div>` after the floated ones, then set give it the property `overflow:hidden`. Block elements with their horizontal overflow hidden will clear any previously floated elements and fill remaining space:

**CSS**

```
#text_area_left {
    float:left;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

#text_area_wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

#text_area_right {
    float:right;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='text_area_row'>
    <div id='text_area_left'>Left</div>
    <div id='text_area_right'>Right</div>
    <div id='text_area_wrapper'>
        <div id='text_area'>CENTERED</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/4Jm59/)

Comment: Probably the, current, optimal solution is source order is not a factor.

Comment: Is it possible to make centered - centered by row width, but non via space available? My right and left text is changing and center element jumps.

Answer (score 0):

You should just float all of the elements to the left and set your margin properly based on the width of your pages elements, and the width of the page itself.

There is no float center.

Edit:
You could however set the margin of your centered element to margin: 0 auto; Which would allow it to be centered on the page.

Comment: Eesh, what was I thinking, for some reason I thought that if everything had widths that didn't fill up the screen, that the center item wouldn't have to be floated.  Dang.

Answer (score 0):

Well, left and right are already in the correct position. So, in order to center the remaining , use the  tags. Be warned, it is a bit troublesome, but usually works fine. So 
`<center>  <div id='text_area_wrapper'> <div id='text_area'> Centered 
</div> 
</div>`

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and is no longer valid HTML